# Vertical aligning text in overlay of image

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

Having some trouble getting the desired effect on an image overlay with responsive image. What I want is upon hovering over the image, the colour block and text to appear as shown, but for the text to be in the vertical centre of the div. I have tried vertical-middle but it doesn't seem to be working. Can't make the width and height set value as need to collapse and expand. If anyone can help i'd appreciate it. Thanks

Code, CSS below

```css
.overlay-box {
   position: relative;
}
.overlay {
  display: none;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background-color: rgba(38,150,198,0.5);
}
.overlay p {
   color: #ffffff;
   text-align: center;
}
.overlay-box:hover .overlay {
     display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">

      <div class="overlay-box">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">
              
                   <div class="overlay">
                   
                          <p>1st line<br>2nd line<br><br>
                          3rd line</p>
                   </div>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/2000x2000" class="img-responsive "/></a>


      </div>

  </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the overlay with another div(since `table`s seem to ignore their `height` and `width` when they're `absolute`) and add `position:absolute` to it. Then add `dislpay:table` and `dislpay:table-cell; vertical-align:middle` for the child divs.

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/65cvzcev/

Answer (score 2):

```css
img{
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
.overlay-box {
   position: relative;
}
.overlay {
  display: none;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background-color: rgba(38,150,198,0.5);
}
.overlay:before {
content: '';
display: inline-block;
width: 1px;
height: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
border: 1px solid;
}
.overlay p {
   color: #ffffff;
   text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 90%;
}
.overlay-box:hover .overlay {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">

  <div class="overlay-box">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
          
               <div class="overlay">
               
                      <p>1st line<br>2nd line<br><br>
                      3rd line</p>
               </div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/2000x2000" class="img-responsive "/></a>


  </div>

  </div>

  </div>
```